# Fixing scope/context mistake in Node.js with Bluebird promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I thought I had finally grasped some fundamental javascript notions thanks to [this awesome video playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEq7Ehw-qk8&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABI011EYc-avPOsk1YsMUe_) : callbacks, scope and context were not a headcrack anymore.

And then, I decided to use promises (bluebird in Node.js)... Those problems arise again, and I guess I don't understand how scope and context work with promises. Here is a test I ran :

```js
function testit(){
  for (var i=0 ; i<3 ; i++) {
    var test = i;
    console.log(test);
    
    Promise
    .delay(5000) // do some async operations...
    .then( () => {
        console.log(test);
    });
  }
  return("finished");
}
console.log(testit());

//// What I hoped to see :
// 0, 1, 2, finished, 0, 1, 2

//// What happens :
// 0, 1, 2, finished, 2, 2, 2
```

Here I am, back into scope/context trouble. To fix this, I found bluebird `Promise.bind()`, which gave me :

```js
function testit(){
  for (var i=0 ; i<3 ; i++) {
    var test = i;
    console.log(test);
    
    Promise
    .bind(this, test)
    .delay(5000)
    .then( (test) => {
        console.log(test);
    });
  }
  return("finished");
}
console.log(testit());

//// What happens :
// 0, 1, 2, finished, 0, 1, 2
```

Yipee ! I have a workaround ! But it is clearly not handy when chaining `.next()` methods : I would have to pass the value of `test` from one promise to another... Can't do that in my code, in which I chain many different functions/methods.

So, is there a cleaner way to "bind"/"retain some values" coming from a `for` loop when working with promises in Node.js ?

---

EDIT : I'm thinking about a closure for the promise chain inside the loop :

```js
function testit(){
  for (var i=0 ; i<3 ; i++) {
    var test = i;
    console.log(test);
    
    (function (test){
      Promise
      .delay(5000) // do some async operations...
      .then( () => {
          console.log(test);
      });
    })(test);
  }
  return("finished");
}
console.log(testit());

//// What happens :
// 0, 1, 2, finished, 0, 1, 2
```

It works too, and that's the best code I have so far. But my initial question remains : is there a better/cleaner way to achieve the initially expected result ?

---

CONCLUSION : The accepted answer is probably the cleanest way to manage async operations inside loops. Using a closure function declared outside the loop rocks. Thx Rob M. !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closure is your best bet here, otherwise `test` will be bound to the parent scope (not the `Promise` callback's scope) and you will continue seeing the run time value of `test`, rather than the call time value that you desire.

```
function getPromise(index) {
   return Promise
    .delay(5000)
    .resolve('index: ')
    .then((prefix) => {
        console.log(prefix + index);
    });
}

function testit(){
  for (var i=0 ; i<3 ; i++) {
    var test = i;
    console.log(test);
    getPromise(i);
  }
  console.log('finished');
}
```

`.bind` is a perfectly acceptable approach though if that works better for you

Comment: Thx for this answer, I just thought about it (look at the edit in my question) ! I understand why and how, but can't I avoid a closure in such a case ? If so, I guess closures are mandatory for any for loop containing async operations ?

Comment: Closure's are indeed mandatory, and there is no better way of doing this. `test` is defined and set in a scope above your Promise, and since your code is asynchronous and not capturing the variable into its own scope, it is using the run time value, not the call time value

Comment: Oh, and I wonder if there is an efficiency concern with the closure function : I declare an anonymous closure inside the loop while you declare and name it outside. The way I wrote it feels more readable to me ("ok, so here I'm just wrapping the stuff in a closure"), but I guess your way is more efficient with only one function declaration ?

Comment: You are correct, it is more efficient to define an external function then to define n internal functions or use bind. Though I agree that it is more readable to see the operation inline, comments and naming can hopefully minimize confusion

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Looking back, my question had nothing to do with promises : I should have named it "closure for js async operations inside loops" ;-)

Comment: My pleasure, and no worries about Promises vs. Closure for async, that's what you were trying to figure out! (and hopefully this helped)